# How to prove SPRT terminates with probability unity?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, sequential-analysis

Can anyone provide me the easily explainable proof of 'SPRT terminates with probability unity'?

To be more specific- 'Prove that SPRT terminates with probability unity'

Answer (score 4):

SPRT terminates at the $N$-th trial where $$N:=\min\left\{n\in \mathbb Z^{> 0}\big | \sum_{i=1}^n z_i~\geq \ln A ~\lor~\leq \ln B\right\} .\tag 1$$ Then it is needed to prove

$$ \mathbb P\{N<\infty\} =1.\tag 2$$ Define $c = \ln A-\ln B.$

Let $\zeta_k$ be the sum of $z_i$ in the $k$-th segment of length $r$ comprising of elements ranging from $\overline{k-1}~r+1$ to $kr.$ So, if SPRT never terminates, then

$$ |\zeta_k| < c ~~~\forall~ k ~\in \mathbb Z^{>0}. \tag 3$$

Note each $\zeta_k$ follow the same distribution.

Define $$Q_r := \mathbb P\{|\zeta_1|< c\}.\tag 4$$

Now, for $t\in \mathbb Z^{>0}, $

\begin{align}\mathbb P\{N >   t+r\} &= \mathbb P\left\{\ln B < \sum_{i=1}^j z_i<\ln A, ~\forall ~j \in S_{t+r+1}\right\}\\ & \leq \mathbb P\left\{\ln B < \sum_{i=1}^j z_i<\ln A, ~\forall ~j \in S_{t+1}~\land~j\in \{t+r\}\right\}\\ &= \mathbb P\left\{\ln B < \sum_{i=1}^j z_i<\ln A, ~\forall ~j \in S_{t+1}\right\}\times \mathbb P\left\{\left|\sum_{i= t+1}^{t+r} z_i\right|< c\right\}\\ &= \mathbb P\left\{\ln B < \sum_{i=1}^j z_i<\ln A, ~\forall ~j \in S_{r+1}\right\}\times \underbrace{\mathbb P\{|\zeta_1| < c\}}_{=~Q_r}\\ &= \mathbb P\{N> t\}~Q_r.\tag 5\label 5\end{align}

Consider $t = (k-1)~ r, ~~k\in\mathbb Z^{>0}\setminus\{1\}. $ Then, using $\eqref 5,$ recursively it can be shown \begin{align}\mathbb P\{N> kr\}&\leq \mathbb P\{N > (k-1) ~r\}~Q_r\\ &\vdots \\&\leq Q_r^{k-1}.\tag 6\label 6\end{align}

Now for a certain $s\in \mathbb Z^{>0}, $ by Archimedean Property, one can find the largest $k\in \mathbb Z^{>0}$ such that $s > kr. $ Then, by $\eqref{6}, $

$$ \begin{align}\mathbb P\{N > s \} &\leq \mathbb P\{N > kr\}\\&\leq Q_r^{k-1}.\tag 7\end{align}$$

Therefore, it suffices to prove that $Q_r < 1.$

WLOG, assume $\mathbb P\{z_i> 0\}>0;$ therefore for very large $r,~\mathbb P\{z_i> c/r\}> 0.$

Now,

\begin{align}1- Q_r &= \mathbb P\{|\zeta_1|\geq c\}\\& \geq \mathbb P\{\zeta_1\geq c\}\\ &\geq \mathbb P\{z_i\geq c/r,~~\forall i\in S_{r+1}\}\\&\geq\left[ \mathbb P\{z_i\geq c/r\}\right]^r\\&> 0.\tag 8\end{align}

$\square$

---

### References:

$[\rm I]$ Sequential Analysis, *Abraham Wald*, Dover Publications, $2004,$ appendix  $\rm A. 1,$ pp. $157-158.$

$\rm [II]$ Statistical Inference, *M. Rajagopalan, P. Dhanavanthan,* PHI Learning, $2012,$ chapter $13, $ pp. $352-353.$